# GraphQL filters in GatsbyJS

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm having trouble understanding how to write filters for GraphQL queries in GatsbyJS.

This works:

```
filter: { contentType: { in: ["post", "page"] }
```

I basically need the reverse of that, like:

```
filter: { "post" in: { contentTypes } } // where contentTypes is array
```

That doesn't work because "NAME is expected" (where "post" is in my example).

After going through GatsbyJS [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/) I found this:

```
elemMatch: short for element match, this indicates that the field you are filtering will return an array of elements, on which you can apply a filter using the previous operators

filter:{
  packageJson:{
    dependencies:{
      elemMatch:{
        name:{
          eq:"chokidar"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Great! That's what I need! So I try that, and I get:

```
error GraphQL Error Field "elemMatch" is not defined by type markdownRemarkConnectionFrontmatterTagsQueryList_2.
```

Keywords defined in [markdownRemarkConnectionFrontmatterTagsQueryList_2](https://github.com/fabien0102/gatsby-starter/blob/master/src/graphql-types.d.ts#L3602) are:

- eq: string | null;
- ne: string | null;
- regex: string | null;
- glob: string | null;
- in: Array | null;

Why am I limited to these keywords when more keywords such as `elemMatch` are mentioned in docs? Why am I not allowed to use the filter structure "element in: { array }"?

How can I create this filter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Filter by value in an array

Let's say you have a markdown blog with `categories` as an array of string, you can filter posts with "historical" in `categories` like this:

```
{
  allMarkdownRemark(filter:{
    frontmatter:{
      categories: {
       in: ["historical"]
      }
    }
  }) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        frontmatter {
          categories
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can try this query out in any of the graphiq blocks in [Gatsby.js docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/).

---

### ElemMatch

I think `elemMatch` is only 'turned on' for fields with array of objects; something like `comments: [{ id: "1", content: "" }, { id: "2", content: ""}]`. This way, you can apply further filters on the fields of each `comment`:

```
comments: { elemMatch: { id: { eq: "1" } } }
```

Here's an example you can try out in the graphiq blocks in gatsby docs:

```
// only show plugins which have "@babel/runtime" as a dependency
{
  allSitePlugin (filter:{
    packageJson:{
      dependencies: {
        elemMatch: {
          name: {
            eq: "@babel/runtime"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }) {
    edges {
      node {
        name
        version
        packageJson {
          dependencies {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The first query you gave works in the toy examples, but it doesn't work in the real case. I'm getting error `GraphQL Error Variable "$tag" of type "String" used in position expecting type "[String]".` The exact filter I used here was `filter: { frontmatter: { tags: { in: $tag } } }` which looks identical to your query.

Comment: Hey @AtteJuvonen! my bad, have you tried `tags: {in: [$tag] }`?

Comment: Thanks, it works! This is really surprising. I would have expected a filter for "[a,b] in [b]" to return false (when all elements in [a,b] are not found in [b]), but it does return true, like I want it to.

Comment: Glad it helps! I also think it is a bit unintuitive. Also it seems like when you use query variable, it’s more nitpicking about filter keyword typing. Let me edit the answer